# How to web scrab from txt file

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup

Let's say I use online tool like HTML Source Code Viewer
then I input a link then they generate the HTML Source Code.
Then select only the `<li>` tags that I want, something like this

```
<li class='item'><a class='list-link' href='https://foo1.com'><img src='https://foo1.com/imgfoo1.jpg' /></a></li><li class='item'><a class='list-link' href='https://foo2.com'><img src='https://foo1.com/imgfoo2.jpg' /></a></li><li class='item'><a class='list-link' href='https://foo3.com'><img src='https://foo1.com/imgfoo3.jpg' /></a></li>
```

so yeah, sometimes it's one long line, then put them to a text name urlcontainer.txt

So, how should I scrab that?
Because when I run the code below on python using terminal

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

page_html = np.genfromtxt('urlcontainer.txt',dtype='str')

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #I got the error on this line
```

And this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 225, in __init__
    markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 157, in prepare_markup
    exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 352, in __init__
    markup, override_encodings, is_html, exclude_encodings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.markup, self.sniffed_encoding = self.strip_byte_order_mark(markup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 280, in strip_byte_order_mark
    if (len(data) >= 4) and (data[:2] == b'\xfe\xff') \
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The thing is, when I type page_html on the terminal, this is the value :

```
array(['<li', "class='item'><a", "class='list-link'",
       "href='https://foo1.com'><img",
       "src='https://foo1.com/imgfoo1.jpg'", '/></a></li><li',
       "class='item'><a", "class='list-link'",
       "href='https://foo2.com'><img",
       "src='https://foo1.com/imgfoo2.jpg'", '/></a></li><li',
       "class='item'><a", "class='list-link'",
       "href='https://foo3.com'><img",
       "src='https://foo1.com/imgfoo3.jpg'", '/></a></li>'], 
      dtype='|S34')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the file as you normally would. No need to use NumPy.

```
with open("urlcontainer.txt") as f:
    page = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
```

Then, carry on with your parsing activities.